# Deep learning on high-precision data

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

**Task**

Suppose the following problem for the neural network. Given a real number x it should output 1 if x is equal to a (i.e. 7.123456789) and output 0 otherwise.

**Dataset**

For the problem, we construct a dataset of 2000 samples, where 1000 samples are equal to a. Other 1000 samples are distinct from a and randomly sampled "far enough" from a, where "far enough" is determined by 2 parameters: gap (< 1) and sparsity (> 1). Each sample is uniformly sampled from (a - gap*sparsity, a - gap) U (a + gap, a + gap*sparsity). In other words, the gap determines the number of significant decimals and sparsity determines the variance of x.

**Model**

Feed-forward network with a single hidden layer with ReLU activations (hidden_dim neurons). Adam optimizer with standard parameters, 1e-4 learning rate, 2000 training epochs, BCE loss. float64 weights and float64 input tensors.

**Results**

[Best validation accuracy as a function of gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUwz5.png)

[Validation accuracies over iterations for different gaps and hidden_dim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXNsi.png)

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to embed images...

**Question**

As can be seen from the figures, lower the gap, harder the problem for the neural network (sparsity is fixed to 1e2). And for the gap lower than 1e-4 it cannot learn the difference. Below is the example of 10 samples along with their labels for 1e-4 gap and 1e2 sparsity:

```
(array([[7.113817389875074 ],
        [7.123456789123456 ],
        [7.121479348058312 ],
        [7.123456789123456 ],
        [7.123456789123456 ],
        [7.11874792046549  ],
        [7.1248334895646215],
        [7.123456789123456 ],
        [7.131370982033207 ],
        [7.118704508563716 ]]),
 array([0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]))
```

I cannot find any literature or tips for such a kind of data. Can anyone recommend some? I think the performance can be significantly improved with a non-standard weight initialization but I am surprised that there is no literature on this. Moreover, from the mathematical viewpoint precision should not be a problem at all (density of real numbers).

The described task is a toy problem, but I am interested in it because I have high-precision spectroscopic measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear whether such an approach would be useful for your actual problem or simply for the toy example, but you should **normalize** your data such that the range of expected inputs falls within a meaningful range (A common input range would be [-1,1]. This seems to be an issue related to the *implementation* of neural networks in common deep learning architectures rather than the *theory* of deep learning architectures (although technically a 1-layer feed-forward neural network is not "deep"). Though a theoretical network could learn a mapping at arbitrary precision, in practice the weights and biases are represented with limited precision so you're limited in essentially the number of digits for a quantity you can reliably predict. The above numbers have enough significant figures that they are nearing the limit of double precision float representation and beyond the limit of single precision floats. So most of the "usable precision" in the model bias is wasted specifying the first significant figures i.e. the mean (that are shared amongst almost all of the data) and if the bias cannot fully capture the mean distribution then some of the "usable precision" of the weights is wasted trying to capture the residual of the mean not captured by the bias parameters. This is unlikely to lead to good performance.

By normalizing, you can make the bias fitting task much easier (the bias is close to 0, and at a minimum the "usable precision" of the float parameters can be meaningfully spent fitting the data. I suspect that solving the bias problem will improve performance by freeing the model weights from the task of estimating the residual of the mean not estimated by the bias parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my task of interest I have values from (0, 1000] and need to distinguish them at 4 decimals. If I normalize them to [-1, 1] then I need to distinguish the values at 8 decimals (values are distributed across the whole (0, 1000] range and not centroided like in a toy example), so I was trying to avoid scalings to small intervals.

Comment: I see. Yeah a cursory look at the literature on my part didn't find any papers on this topic, and I think it's actually a pretty interesting question. In general, it seems that tasks requiring both high precision and a large range of possible input values may be difficult to work with in the floating point space.

Comment: In any case, I'd recommend adding additional layers, intuitively this would allow one layer to learn a coarse representation, the next to learn a fine "offset" from the first, and so on. I also wonder whether a non deep learning ML approach may achieve the desired output better

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I had a similar idea. Actually I have a Transformer on continuous inputs, where each value of a sequence is precise. And I had an idea to prepend additional deep position-wise feed-forward layers that could firstly "stretch the space" avoiding the problem of high-precision and then learn the representations of interest. By "stretch the space" I mean something like the initialization of weights with high values.